# how to set an ios app icon with Qt framework

Tags: ios, xcode, qt

I use Qt sdk (https://www.qt.io/blog/2013/03/05/qt-for-ios-preview) to write an iPhone app.
I can't figure out how to set the application icon.
I drag and dropped a 57*57 png file named Icon.png in the Xcode target->summary->App icon but nothing seems to happened. Same is for Launch images.

Do someone achieve to set the app icon using Xcode project generated by qmake?

Comment: Try [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/appicon.html#setting-the-application-icon-on-mac-os-x).

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for ios.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put

```
QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += icons
```

in the pro file.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-34624

Your Code Snippet did not work for me.